# What is the structure of quantum graph code [[4,0,3]]? Or does it exist?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, graph-states

What is the structure of quantum graph code [[4,0,3]]? Or does it exist? How the edges are connected?

Comment: Potentially useful resource: https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the parameters given on [CodeTables](http://www.codetables.de/), it seems like this does not exist. There is a [[4,0,2]] code.

[image: CodeTables screenshot]

But there is a [entanglement-assisted code](http://www.codetables.de/EAQECC/qubit.php) with parameters [[4,0,3;1]]